# java eclipse mix array of String and int

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, int

```
public class Student {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] array2d = new Object[3][7];

    array2d[0][0] = "student name";
    array2d[0][1] = "firstest";
    array2d[0][2] = "secondtest ";
    array2d[0][3] = "schoolworks";
    array2d[0][4] = "homeworks";
    array2d[0][5] = "finaltest";
    array2d[0][6] = "total grade";

    array2d[1][0] = "jack";
    array2d[1][1] = new Integer(15);
    array2d[1][2] = new Integer(10);
    array2d[1][3] = new Integer(7);
    array2d[1][4] = new Integer(8);
    array2d[1][5] = new Integer(35);
    array2d[1][6] = new Integer(75);

    array2d[2][0] = "john";
    array2d[2][1] = new Integer(19);
    array2d[2][2] = new Integer(15);
    array2d[2][3] = new Integer(9);
    array2d[2][4] = new Integer(5);
    array2d[2][5] = new Integer(30);
    array2d[2][6] = new Integer(78);


    for (int row = 0; row < array2d.length;  row++) {

        for (int colums = 0; colums < array2d[row].length; colums++)
            System.out.println(array2d[row][colums]);
    }
```

I want to print 2d mix array of String and int on this order. table 
new to java and the site bear with me

```
student name firstest secondtest schoolworks homeworks finaltest total grade 
    jack        15        10          8           7         35         67
```

print table on this order
with my bad english and java i edited as much as i can

Comment: You are setting `array2d[1][1] = new Integer(15);` and then `array2d[1][1] = new Integer(19);` maybe you meant to do `array2d[1][2] = new Integer(19);` the second time around? If you don't do that you'll get a NullPointerException if you try and println a null value.

Comment: You need to edit your question to make amendments. Comments just look messy.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. But your English has to be sufficient to be able to understand the rules in [ask], and to understand our answers. Please don't put code in comments, and please don't put text that is not related to the problem like "help help help".

Answer (score 1):

To print out something looking like how you show in your post takes a bit of thought, and has many steps involved. Here is something to get you started:

```
//First we need to set a spacing for each item,
//else the table will look bad and not be in line:
int spacing = 14;

//Now loop through the array and store each item in `rowToPrint`
//The for loop will repeat for each row
for (int row = 0; row < array2d.length; row++)
{
    //Create a string to store a whole row for printing:
    String rowToPrint = "";

    //The for loop will repeat for each column
    for (int column = 0; column < array2d[row].length; column++)
    {
        //get previous row items
        String previousItems = rowToPrint;

        //get next array item
        String newItem = array2d[row][column];

        //work out array item length
        int length = array2d[row][column].length();

        //work out padding for this item by doing (Spacing - array item length), and add blank spaces.
        //Example: 14(spacing) - 8 (item length) = 6 spaces of padding
        String padding = String.format("%" + (spacing - length) + "s", "");

        //now add add it all together
        rowToPrint = previousItems + newItem + padding;
    }

    //Now print current row in full with spacing/padding
    System.out.println(rowToPrint);
}
```

This code could be a lot simpler, but I have kept it seperated and clear so you can easily see what is happening and easily make changes.

You also need to change parts of your code, else the example will not work:

Change from this `Object[][] array2d = new Object[3][7];`, to this `String[][] array2d = new String[3][7];`, because this will not work otherwise `.length()`, and would require a bit more code to handle it.

Also don't assign an integer like this `array2d[1][1] = new Integer(15);`, do it like this instead `array2d[1][1] = "15";` or like `array2d[1][1] = "" + new Integer(15);`. If you need to turn the data back into an integer then use something like this: `Integer.parseInt(array2d[1][1])`

Example output for the above code:

```
student name  firstest      secondtest    schoolworks   homeworks     finaltest     total grade   
jack          15            10            7             8             35            75            
john          19            15            9             5             30            78
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with the above code:

Your 2D array matrix, when printing is looping on objects which is weird, use int for indexes.

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Object[][] array2d = new Object[3][7];

    array2d[0][0] = "اسم الطالب";
    array2d[0][1] = "اختبارالاول";
    array2d[0][2] = "اختبارالثاني";
    array2d[0][3] = "المشاركه";
    array2d[0][4] = "الواجبات";
    array2d[0][5] = "الاختبار النهائي";
    array2d[0][6] = "المجموع";

    array2d[1][0] = "عبدالله";
    array2d[1][1] = new Integer(15);
    array2d[1][2] = new Integer(10);
    array2d[1][3] = new Integer(7);
    array2d[1][4] = new Integer(8);
    array2d[1][5] = new Integer(35);
    array2d[1][6] = new Integer(75);

    array2d[1][0] = "محمد"; // Not sure if you should be reassigning the array elements, although you can
    array2d[1][1] = new Integer(19);
    array2d[1][2] = new Integer(15);
    array2d[1][3] = new Integer(9);
    array2d[1][4] = new Integer(5);
    array2d[1][5] = new Integer(30);
    array2d[1][6] = new Integer(78);

    for (int row = 0; row < array2d.length; row++)
    {

        for (int colums = 0; colums < array2d[row].length; colums++)
            System.out.println(array2d[row][colums]);
    }
}}
```